# Iterating over an IEnumerable in Javascript for Chartjs

Tags: javascript, c#, chart.js

I have hit upon a problem where by I have an `IEnumerable<string>` of labels and an `IEnumerable<double[]>` of data in my MVC model object, and I would like to plot these values using Chartjs.

I pass both of in to my javascript function, which I trying to make plot the chart.

The Chartjs syntax is such that I want, in effect:

```
var data = {
               ... chart info e.g. colors, etc.
               datasets: [
                   {
                       label: labels[0], // My first label
                       data: datas[0]    // My first double[]
                   },
                   // Repeat for each data/label combo
                   {
                       label: labels[n], // My n-th label
                       data: datas[n]    // My n-th double[]
                   }
               ]
           };
```

Given my two collections, how can I extract the information within them appropriately? Clearly the lengths of these collections need to be the same, as there is a one-to-one association. I did try combing them in to a Tuple but I think that will make it more complicated on the js side.

Or does anyone know an easier way to achieve the same end result with ChartJS?

I'm comfortable with C# but Javascript is new to me.

Comment: Could always [zip](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267698(v=vs.100).aspx) the two collections and then use a [JavaScriptSerializer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer(v=vs.110).aspx) on the result.

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly send a tuple to the client side and split it up easily with java-script. You could do a simple ajax call to get your tuple as a Json object and then split it up into two arrays. Those arrays could then be used in the chart.js label and data spots.

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'AjaxCall/getChartObjects',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {},
    success: function (data) { //data here being the tuple recieved from server
        //receive the tuple as a single Json object and split it up easily with some seperate arrays
        dblArray= [] 
        $.each(data.Item1, function (index, value) {
            dblArray.push(value.text); //label array
        }
        descArray= []
        $.each(data.Item2, function (index, value) {
            descArray.push(value.dblTxt); //data array
        }
    },
    error: function (xhr, status, error) {
        console.log('Error: ' + error.message);
    }
});
```

Sending the tuple from the controller would be something like:

```
//tuple sends two objects together- both job arrays will be seperated 
//and used in observables on client side
var chartObjects = Tuple.Create(chartData, chartLabel);

return Json(chartObjects, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

You would then have the arrays that you need to place in the chart properties:

```
var barChartData = {
                labels: descArray, //array labels
                datasets: [
                    {
                        type: "Bar",
                        strokeColor: "black",
                        pointColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                        pointstrokeColor: "white",
                        data: dblArray,

                    }
                ]
            }
```

I guess I'm not entirely sure if this is what you were looking for. Let me know if you have questions.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I want to also be able to pass in multiple tuples such that I have a many `{...}` in the setting of the `datasets` of `var barChartData`. Do you know how I would loop over an enumerable of tuples in JS?

Comment: Javascript doesn't care if you are passing list, enumerables, arrays or anything. The objects that you pass to client side as Json objects will be dealt with the same in javascript. I guess I am not fully understanding what you are asking. You can loop over objects in JS using for-loops or like I did above with jquery $.each loops.